# Downloading Excel file with using Selenium and C#

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to download an Excel file on the web site, but I think i did something wrong. I have HTML code:

```html
<label class="pager">
<input onclick="excelForm.submit()" type="image" value="Excel" src="/YeniSistem/images/Excel_Document_Icon.png">
</label>
```

What I want to do this with using Selenium I want to click that input with using C#. I have tried in many ways, like:

```js
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div/label[2]/input")).Click();
```

and:

```
 driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//div[@id='contentContainer']/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]")).Click();
```

and:

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//input[contains(@value , 'Excel')]")).Click();
```

Also I tried previous codes without `.` in frond of XPath. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? Do you get an error, upon clicking?

Comment: The issue here is i can not click the XPath location, i get error like `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//html/body/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div/div/label[2]/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)' `

Comment: Have you tried XPath: `.//label[@class='pager']/input`?

Comment: Yes I tried also not working. There are more then one 'pager' class in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, I understand that you are trying to download an excel file instead of XPath you can use the following code:

```js
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("link here",@"file_path.xlsx");
```

Comment: Yes, it is that I want to do.